# How to control how often Spring Boot Admin calls a custom HealthIndicator?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I have a custom Spring Boot `HealthIndicator` as follows:

```
public class MyServiceHealth implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        
        log.debug("checking service health");
        // code omitted that verifies service is working
        return Health.up().build();
    }
    
}
```

Spring Boot Admin calls this `health` method every 20 seconds. This is a problem because this health check is expensive. I only need to run this health check once a day. How can I schedule this health check to run once a day?

Comment: why in `HealthIndicator` looks like that should be handled in different endpoint

Comment: My goal is to verify that once a day this service and a few others in different apps don't return an error. If they do, then I want to send an email to an administrator so they can correct it. Only once a day is required. I thought implementing `HealthIndicator` was the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a health check, store the result in memory and the time you performed it. When another healthcheck is requested, only do a new check (and store it) if there is longer than 24 hours since the original check, otherwise just return the previously stored result.